# How can I get mail.app to go to the item below a deleted item in my inbox?

Tags: mail.app, sort

When I'm reviewing mail, I like to have my most recent on top, and I work backwards in time (i.e., down the list).

But when I delete an item, rather than going to the next *lower* item in the list (like Outlook does), it goes to the closest item that's **newer.**    Because it's based on always going to the closest item that's **newer**, I can't even get the desired behavior in going from new to old by reversing my sort order.

Am I missing a preference somewhere, or do I really have to either hit the down arrow after each delete, or work from oldest to newest if I want to save those precious keystrokes?

Comment: It's only one keystroke.. What you *could* do is use the down arrow to read through all of your mail, and then use COMMAND+Click to select all of the items to delete, and then COMMAND+Delete to delete them..

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be changed via a hidden preference. Open up the Terminal app and type this:

defaults write com.apple.mail IgnoreSortOrderWhenSelectingAfterDelete 1

Then, restart Mail.app.